# How to have S3, Cloudfiles, etc download a file directly from a URL?

Tags: amazon-s3, rackspace-cloudfiles

I'm looking at having to transfer a lot of large files from a 3rd party system to a cloud based file storage system, such as Rackspace Cloudfiles or Amazon S3. I'm not limited to just using those two, however.

What I'm trying to find is a way to just let those services download the files directly, once provided with a public URL, in order to speed up the transfer and avoid having to setup something in the middle that relays each file.

Is there a service out there that has an option like this available via an API or a file list upload?

Answer (score 0):

All modem cloud (object) storage service meet your requirement, I think.
For exmaple, AWS S3, supports set canned ACL to public when putting object (uploading file).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: I read over that document and I don't see where it lets me tell S3 to download the file from a public URL anywhere. Am I just missing something?

Comment: Look over the document carefully. If you use S3 API, just add header x-amz-acl:public-read in your put object request, then you can get the file from public url: http://[bucket name].s3.amazonaws.com/[file name]

Comment: If you use s3cmd: s3cmd put [file name] s3://[bucket name] -P (-P means public)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it shortly and confirm.